# Without prior knowledge of Scheme's floor and rounding functions, how can SICP Exercise 1.45 (making an nth root function) be completed?

Tags: scheme, lisp, rounding, sicp

While completing [SICP's Exercise 1.45](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%25_thm_1.45), one soon notices that the number of times that the `average-damp` procedure needs to be applied to find the nth root of a number is very well approximated by the base 2 logarithm of n, rounded down. In other words, we use `(floor (/ (log n) (log 2)))`. Numerous [online](https://billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/08/sicp-145-computing-nth-roots.html) [solutions](https://codology.net/post/sicp-solution-exercise-1-45/) take this exact approach, with the only exception that I can find being [a complex and uncommented solution from the Schemewiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.45).

However, as far as I've been able to find, *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* does not introduce any form of rounding (e.g. `floor`) until after the chapter where this exercise appears. This raises the question: do we know anything at all about how this exercise was intended to be completed by readers? Or failing that, is there any obvious way to do it (i.e. round down `(/ (log n) (log 2))`) without prior knowledge of `floor`?

Comment: Repeated division by two springs to mind.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ordinary division doesn't round, so that's out. I considered using `remainder` but the fault of that is obvious.

Comment: The question does say: "_Assume that any arithmetic operations you need are available as primitives._"

Comment: @adabsurdum True, but that's vague to the point of uselessness.

Comment: @J.Mini You don't need to round anything.

Comment: @molbdnilo I suspect that you've spotted something that I've completely missed. That's an answer that I'd love to see. How are you going to get away with applying average-damp a non-integer number of times?

Comment: why "complex"? not complex, does exactly what you've described. calculates power by repeated squaring, and log_Base_2  by repeated multiplication by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that you need to know about the *Scheme* procedure `floor` at all, because the instructions for the exercise say explicitly that you may "*assume that any arithmetic operations you need are available as primitives.*" If you need `floor`, you may assume that it is available.

But as it turns out, you do not need `floor` anyway. Just define `repeated` in such a way that floating point counts are *effectively* floored:

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (< n 2)
      f
      (lambda (x) (f ((repeated f (- n 1)) x)))))
```

Combining this with the other definitions from the book lets you define `nth-root` with no `floor` procedure:

```
(define (nth-root x n)
  (fixed-point ((repeated average-damp
                          (/ (log n) (log 2)))
                (lambda (y) (/ x (expt y (- n 1)))))
               1.0))
```

Comment: This is a work of genius. I even forgot that the book had already given us a procedure for x^n (`expt` is defined at the [start of section 1.2.4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.4) and it returns x^n, and not anything to do with the mathematical constant e, as I foolishly thought).